# Reverse Javascript triggered CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

This may be a stupid question but I am struggling. I want a slide in-out navigation menu for small screens, triggered by javascript. This is what I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="responsive">
  <ul class="nav-list unstyled">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Information</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Magazine</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**SCSS**

```
nav.responsive {
  ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background-color: #fafafa;
    li {
      a {
        display: block;
        padding: 12px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
      }
    }
    &.menu-list-active {
      display: block;
      animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    ul {
      display: block;
      transform: none;
      li {
        display: inline-block;
        a {
          border-bottom: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  div.nav-mobile {
    display: block;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #999999;
    cursor: pointer;
    &.menu-button-active {
      background-color: #555555;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 720px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in {
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// Create the mobile navigation toggle button

var mobile = document.createElement('div');
mobile.className = 'nav-mobile';
document.querySelector('nav.responsive').appendChild(mobile);

// Set some variables

var mobileNav = document.querySelector('.nav-mobile');
var navList = document.querySelector('.nav-list');

// Handle showing the menu
mobileNav.onclick = function () {
  this.classList.toggle('menu-button-active');
  navList.classList.toggle('menu-list-active');
};
```

This is working well, and the menu is sliding in as I want. However I also want it to slide out again when the `nav-mobile` button is clicked. I have tried animating the `ul` initially but that means when the screen size is reduced then you see the menu sliding out which I don't want. Ideally when the page loads on a small screen the menu should not be visible.

Is there a way to get this to work as I would like?

**EDIT**

Codepen here:

http://s.codepen.io/mikehdesign/debug/wgLxYp/bZMQWyLvZYVA

Comment: You should use `transition` instead of `animation` here, which will solve your issue. So `animation: slide-in .5s` should just be `transition: transform .4s` on your ul itself. Then it will always neatly animate the transition.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a `transition` instead of an `animation` here. Here is a simplified example:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .4s;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
}

div.active {
  transform: translate(0);
}
```

```html
<div>My Nav</div>
```

As you can see, this does the same kind of animation as yours, except it can be interrupted. Sidenote, using the `:before` or `:after` and clicking it will identify it as the parent node in JS, so you can create your button in pure css and simply check for a click directly on the wrapper and not on links contained therein (`if( event.target === this ){ ... Open and close ... }`), which is a useful system to reduce the amount of clutter in your HTML and completely design your menu in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not quite working as I would like. I have forked my codepen here, with your suggestion implemented: http://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/ggNqqb. You will see as you resize the screen smaller the menu slides out due to that initial transition. I don't want that - I would like it to just disappear and show the trigger, which then controls the slide in-out

Comment: @MikeHarrison This is the most controllable you will get it with pure CSS, and regular users of your site are not resizing your site and will see one or the other and never the - if anything pretty snappy - transition. There is no way to make this work predictably using `animations`. You could add JS to detect the screen change and add a non-transitioning class for a while or something, but I am sure the hassle is certainly not worth it.

Comment: OK thanks - I am going to keep experimenting and see if I can get something. I take your point that it might not be possible, but want to shoot for the best I can

Comment: @MikeHarrison, best of luck with this but one little tip: don't overcomplicate this. This is a feature that would not benefit from a massive amount of JS and CSS for what is basically a feature only developers really use (resizing of browser windows ) :) Good luck!